# Measuring similarity of observations (non numeric)

Tags: correlation, algorithms, euclidean, cosine-similarity, jaccard-similarity

I have a dataset of format :

```
day,measurement1,measurement2
1,a,b
1,a,c
1,f,s
2,a,b
2,a,c
2,f,g
3,a,d
3,a,q
3,f,s
```

In this example day1 is more similar with day2 than day3 as both share measurements : `a,b` `a,c` . There is no ordering to this dataset.

How to compare the simmilarity with each day based on it's two measurement values ?

Maintain a counter for each day where same measurements increment the counter.
day1 & day2 both share `a,b` & `a,c` so simmilarity between day1 & day2 = 2 . Using a table to describe simmilarity :

```
Day Comparison, simmilarity score
day1,day2 , 2
day2,day3 , 0
day1,day3 , 1
```

Is there an algorithm that is similar or same to what I'm looking to implement. My current plan is to implement this from scratch but will use library function if is available.

The objective of this is that I can use the output of this algorithm to find what days have similar measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if correlation is the right word for what you are trying to do.
But did you look into the Gower Similarity Measure or the Jaccard Index? Those are some of the standard ways for measuring (dis)similarity with categorical variables.
They provide values between 0 an 1.